# singe quotes in dynamic sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

What is wrong with this line of code?
SELECT
'IF (SELECT COLUMNPROPERTY('+ OBJECT_ID('' **[+ TABLE_SCHEMA +''].[**' + TABLE_NAME +] ''+',' + ''U'')+',' +''COLUMN_NAME''+','+ ''AllowsNull''+')) =0'

I am trying to script out nullability of columns.This is part of the script not the whole script. This line is giving me hard time.

Comment: paste the line into SSMS and you will find the typos using the highlighting funtion. *Find my typo questions* (particularly showing an excerpt) are off topic on SO.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about *find my typo*

Comment: What is wrong? Well, for a start, using dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are passing invalid parameters to the columnproperty() function.

Here is an example with and without dynamic sql using the Adventure Works 2012 database.

The first example one returns all columns for table 'ProductListPriceHistory' and their nullability.

The second example create dynamic TSQL to returns just one row for the 'EndDate' column in the same table.  It stores the row in a table variable that can be queried with an IF statement.  I like seeing all the relevant data when testing; therefore, I used a table variable to store key data.

I hope this solves your problem.

Good luck.

John

```
-- Test database
use AdventureWorks2012
go

--
-- Non dynamic SQL
--

SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'AllowsNull') AS AllowsNulls
FROM AdventureWorks2012.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = 'ProductListPriceHistory'
GO


--
-- Dynamic SQL
--

-- table variable
declare @var_table TABLE
(
    TABLE_NAME varchar(256),
    COLUMN_NAME varchar(256),
    ALLOWS_NULLS int
);

-- tsql stmt
declare @var_tsql varchar(max) = 
  'USE AdventureWorks2012; ' + 
  ' SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(TABLE_SCHEMA + ''.'' + TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, ''AllowsNull'') AS ALLOWS_NULLS ' + 
  ' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS ' +
  ' WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''ProductListPriceHistory'' AND ' + 
  ' COLUMN_NAME = ''EndDate'' ';

-- save to variable
insert into @var_table
exec (@var_tsql);

-- query the variable
select ALLOWS_NULLS from @var_table;
```

The output from the statements.

[image]

More examples for the user:

```
-- tsql stmt
declare @var_tsql varchar(max) = 
' IF (SELECT COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(''[Production].[ProductListPriceHistory]'',''U''), ''EndDate'', ''AllowsNull'')) = 1 
   PRINT ''Field allows null''
ELSE 
   PRINT ''Field does not allow null'' ';

-- run the statement
exec (@var_tsql);


-- tsql stmt
set @var_tsql  = 
' IF (SELECT COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(''[Production].[ProductListPriceHistory]'',''U''), ''ProductID'', ''AllowsNull'')) = 1 
   PRINT ''Field allows null''
ELSE 
   PRINT ''Field does not allow null'' ';

-- run the statement
exec (@var_tsql);
```

The output is the following.

**Field allows null
Field does not allow null**

Comment: I am trying to script out for the entire database not for a single table. And here is whole query :

Comment: I am trying to script out for the entire DB not for a  table.                                              I am expecting to get :                                                                                                                 IF (SELECT COLUMNPROPERTY( OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[MODEL]','U'),'[DESCRIPTION]','AllowsNull')) =0 
  ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MODEL]  
   ALTER COLUMN [DESCRIPTION]   NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
   ELSE 
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MODEL]  
   ALTER COLUMN [DESCRIPTION]   NVARCHAR(200) NULL

Comment: Remove the [] around DESCRIPTION.  I did the above with print statements.  Works fine.I do not understand why you are fill flopping nullability, but that is another issue.